# How to check if the all the indexes of an ArrayList has no file in them?

Tags: java, android, loops, boolean

I searched and couldn't find a similar issue.
I want to check if all the indexes of an `ArrayList` has no file in them (file does not exist in their path), obviously this must be done via a `for-loop` and a `boolean`, so I want the `boolean` to be like this:

**if all indexes has no file in them `boolean` is true.**

**if one or more or all of the indexes has file in their path `boolean` is false.**

Using the method below I have a problem , if one of the indexes (or should I say the first occurrence) has no file the condition it true , but that is not what I want , I want it to be true only if **all of the indexes has no file in them.**

```
for (int i = 0; i < logopaths.size(); i++) {
            String s = logopaths.get(i);
            File file = new File(s);
            boolean exists = file.exists();
            if (exists){
                // do somethng
            } else {
                // do some other thing
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just count how many times your "if" is false and compare with logopaths.size();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or make it a method:

```
    public boolean fileFound(List<String> logopaths) {
        boolean atLeastOneFileExists = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < logopaths.size() && !atLeastOneFileExists; i++) {
            String s = logopaths.get(i);
            File file = new File(s);
            atLeastOneFileExists = file.exists();
        }
        return atLeastOneFileExists;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you god bless you

Answer (score 1):

Here (:

```
// Array of logo paths
ArrayList<String> logoPaths = new ArrayList<>();

// File variable declaration
File file = null;
// The flag which indicates all the file paths are exists
boolean flag = ture;

for (int i = 0; i < logoPaths.size(); i++) {
    // Creating a file instance in order to get access to file operations
    file = new File(logoPaths.get(i));
    
    // If one file exists the flag will be false and we will break the for loop. 
    // If all the files are not exists the flag will stay true.
    if (file.exists()) {
        flag = false;
        break;
    }
}
```